# Azerty layout with direct number input

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, input-source

I grew used to the azerty layout (which was a bad idea, but I don't have energy to spend months relearning to type).

I would really like however to have the numbers row behave as it does in the normal qwerty layout (number input on press rather than symbol).

This is less for typing purposes than for keyboards shortcuts relying on numbers, which depending from the app either force me to add an awkward shift press or just don't work at all.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

French Numerical might help.
I found this article whilst Googling -

> **[Numbers on the Belgian keyboard](https://ilovemymac.bachibouzouks.com/2011/09/12/numbers-on-the-belgian-keyboard/)**
>
> If you opted for the French or Belgian Apple wireless keyboard, you
>   may experience a strange behavior when using the number keys. On the
>   AZERTY keyboard, the numbers appear on the second top row of keys,
>   together with the accented and special characters.
>
> [image]
>
> Apple Wireless keyboard frHowever, it may be so that when pressing the
>   Caps Lock On, you still get the accented characters instead of the
>   expected numbers. This is a bit of a challenge when needing to enter
>   series of figures.
>
> If so, you have to change the default keyboard in the system
>   preferences, to “Français – numérique” instead of “belge”. Go to
>   System Preferences, in the Language and Text section. Then in the
>   “input method”, select the “Français – numérique” keyboard, and
>   deselect the “Belge” keyboard. From now on, when Caps Lock is on, the
>   number keys will actually return numbers.
>
> [image]

The Keyboard Control Panel has changed slightly since that article was written - it's now accessible on a separate sheet, after hitting the + at the bottom of the pref pane.

[image]